# How to customize HTML Purifier?

Tags: richtext

HTML Purifier is deleting a custom link attribute. As I understand the HTML Purifier docs, it should be possible to customize it to allow a defined attribute. Is there in Craft CMS a defined way for doing such a customizing (like the Redactor configuration)?

Thank you very much for your help!

Edit: Would probably possible in "RichTextFieldType.php" (Line 205ff)?

Comment: Front end? Back end? If it' the back end, Redactor is probably getting involved as well.

Comment: As I understand, HTML Purifier is linked to the richtext field, so front end or back end should be the same. Redactor is not involved, I use a custom Redactor plugin which inserts the custom attribute.

Comment: "Redactor is not involved, I use a custom Redactor plugin" - that doesn't make sense. :)

Comment: Means: Redactor is not part of my problem, because a custom plugin inserts the attribute which is then removed by HTML purifier ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Brad says above, there's no way to configure the RichTextField's HTML Purifier instance – but you could easily create a custom fieldtype that instantiates HTML Purifier w/ different options.

First, scaffold a custom plugin using [pluginfactory.io](https://pluginfactory.io/). Name the plugin what you want, don't enable any components.

Second, create a file called `/fieldtypes/MyPluginHandle_RichTextFieldType.php` inside your custom plugin's directory (replacing `MyPluginHandle` with the actual handle for your plugin, of course).

Third, paste in everything from `craft/app/fieldtypes/RichTextFieldType.php` into your custom fieldtype; then remove everything except the `prepValueFromPost()` and `getName()` methods. Make sure you're returning something different than "Rich Text" from the latter method, and configure `\CHtmlPurifier()` according to your needs inside the `prepValueFromPost()` method.

Finally, install your plugin and convert any existing Rich Text fields to your custom fieldtype.

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to configure the default Rich Text Field's use of HTMLPurifier, unfortunately, though it has been brought up before and is on our list to look at exposing to a config file post Craft 3 launch.

Your custom plugin could create it's own [CHtmlPurifier](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtmlPurifier) instance and configure it however you want, though.

```
$purifier = new \CHtmlPurifier();
$purifier->setOptions(array(
    'Attr.AllowedFrameTargets' => array('_blank'),
    'HTML.AllowedComments' => array('pagebreak'),
    ...
));

$value = $purifier->purify($value);
```